# Using Latex in Django project with django_tex , pdflatex

Tags: django, pdf, latex, pdflatex

I am trying to use Latex to build PDFs in Django project using django_tex , pdflatex. I have made setting such that in django setting.py , under INSTALLED_APPS, TEMPLATES . When server started running and the method is called , it is throwing an error while compiling the latex file .
`Command 'cd "/tmp/tmpvk2or_tb" && pdflatex -interaction=batchmode  texput.tex' returned non-zero exit status 127.`  is the error.
I am attaching my code part in Views.py and also my latex file .

**Views.py**

```
from django_tex.shortcuts import render_to_pdf

template_name = 'test.tex'
context = {'content':'this is the pdf content'}
return render_to_pdf(request, 'test.tex', context, filename='test.pdf')
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{ {{ content }} }

\end{document}
```

Can someone suggest something on this . And Is latex is the better option to generate pdfs with all backgrounds and all than using xhtml2pdf ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your tex template should contain `{{- content -}}` instead of `{{ content }}` (note the extra dashes inside the double braces), as in step 3 of the [quick start guide](https://github.com/weinbusch/django-tex#quick-start) of django-tex?

Comment: @Abby , I have tried but in-vain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code in the settings
LATEX_INTERPRETER = 'pdflatex' and see if it solves.

Comment: You should add this as comment not as answer or open a question yourself

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I changed the answer. Hug!